# Nivo jQuery error. It won't work at all

Tags: jquery, html, nivo-slider

Thanks for your time.
I follow the tutorial, and then the video, but I can not get it to work.

My head looks like this

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="nivo-slider.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"     type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="jquery.nivo.slider.pack.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

And in my body is

```
<div class="slider-wrapper theme-default">
<div id="slider" class="nivoSlider">
    <img src="images/walle.jpg" alt="" />
    <a href="http://dev7studios.com"><img src="images/nemo.jpg" alt="" title="#htmlcaption" /></a>
    <img src="images/toystory.jpg" alt="" title="This is an example of a caption" />
    <img src="images/up.jpg" alt="" />
</div>
</div>
<div id="htmlcaption" class="nivo-html-caption">
    <strong>This</strong> is an example of a <em>HTML</em> caption with <a href="#">a link</a>.
</div>
```

And at the bottom of the body, right before it closes, is

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(window).load(function() {
$('#slider').nivoSlider();
});
</script>
```

I literally copy and pasted everything... I have no idea what is wrong. Any insight is greatly appreciated.

Thanks so much

Comment: How doesn't it work? Do you get any error messages in your JS console?

Comment: there are a bunch of errors...this is one of them..
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'nivoSlider' Index.htm:255
(anonymous function) Index.htm:255
f.event.dispatch jquery.min.js:3
h.handle.i

Comment: and some more like this..
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://redvaultproductions.com/css/screen.css
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://redvaultproductions.com/jquery.nivo.slider.pack.js
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://redvaultproductions.com/nivo-slider.css
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://redvaultproductions.com/images/nemo.jpg

Comment: Judging by your errors - are you sure you are linking to the css and js files in the correct locations? Are they located in your root directory along with this page? I also use Nivo and mine is set up the same as yours but is working fine. Also check to make sure you are not loading jQuery twice (I had that issue before).

Comment: @Shannon I was not linking it to the right spot! Thanks so much! I would so click yours as the answer right now, and if I were allowed to I would upvote it.

Comment: Added as an answer if you'd like to accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not pointing to the correct location for your js and/or css files. Based on your code they should be in the root directory along with this page.

Comment: YOU DID IT. thank you. in light of this I changed it to a new /nivo folder.